# Service Reference and List/Array Types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a problem that I really need solved in any way (changing data types is an option)

Assumptions:

1. Both Program and Service done in VS2008
2. I have complete control over both Program and Service
3. I have a program that is passing a "list" of info to the Service Reference

Example:

Program snippet:

```
IList<string> XMLList = null;
XMLList = new List<string>();

// fill my list up here...  mostly just an "array" of xml-based strings

string[] arrayToSend = new string[XMLList.Count];
arrayToSend = XMLList.ToArray<string>();

string results = DataFeedService.ProcessXMLBatch(arrayToSend);
```

Service Snippet:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ProcessXMLBatch(string[] XMLBatch)
{
       // process the xml here...
       return "done";
}
```

Problem:
It does not consider the string[] that I create in the service to be the same kind of
string array.  It converts it to a type of #namespace.#servicename.ArrayOfString

this code will currently not compile. I have looked around for alternate ways to pass a list or a generic and I keep hitting roadblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing your code to use a `List<string>` rather than an `IList<string>` (I know that's what you're actually using, but declare your variable as such). The `List<T>` class provides an explicit `ToArray()` function that will be faster than the `Enumerable.ToArray<T>` extension method you're employing in your code. This **might** clear up your issues too, but I'm not certain about that.

Also, you do not need

```
string[] arrayToSend = new string[XMLList.Count];
```

Just declare it as

```
string[] arrayToSend;
```

You're already assigning it with the `ToArray()` call; no need to create another one beforehand.

**Edit** Why not instantiate and populate the `ArrayOfString` class that's created in your service reference namespace? It will work just like a `List<string>` (and, in fact, I believe it inherits from it). Use this as the type for your `XMLList`, and just send the `XMLList` variable directly to the function.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions, and am basically receiving the same error:

string[] arrayToSend;
arrayToSend = XMLList.ToArray();
string results = DataFeedService.ProcessXMLBatch(arrayToSend);

yields:
Error 4 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'FileFeedParser.DataFeedService.ArrayOfString' E:\tlatourelle-pc-external\dev\AmazonDataFeed\FeedFileParser\FeedFileParser\Program.cs 223 86 FeedFileParser

Comment: Didn't see your answer, Jeff. You've moved to the top, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Actually I ended up doing the suggestion in the Edit.  I populated the ArrayOfStrings object in the Service Reference.  I then passed this to the Service and it accepted it.  

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `WebMethod` to accept a `List<string>` rather than `string[]` and pass an appropriate type, it should work. ASP.NET services seem to prefer this in my experience.

Also, don't forget to make sure your Service References are up-to-date so that the service wrapper types are correctly created for your code to interact with.

#### Update

Have you tried actually creating the `ArrayOfString` type and populating it, rather than using `string[]` when calling your WebMethod?

Comment: I have also tried this methodology and also receive the ArrayOfString error as described above with the string[] example.  I have also made sure that my references are up-to-date each time I make a change to the service.